# Same FB App, multiple iOS Bundle IDs, with different suffixes?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have two versions of my iPhone app, one is for the appstore and the other an ad-hoc version for internal testing. They have:
- Same FB App ID for both (they both communicate with same backend)
- Two different bundle IDs (so they can both be installed on device)
- Different URL suffixes (empty and 'adhoc')

They both worked properly with login, but when I changed the iOS Bundle ID on the app page on FB admin tool it obviously stopped working: I got "fb_APP_ID_SUFFIX://authorize#error=unknown%5Ferror" as the URL before it called to fbDidNotLogin, on the test app.

If I don't put the iOS bundle ID it works. Do I have any option to still protect the bundle ID and have the other app working?

Comment: Why not create 2 apps in Facebook?

Comment: Because I want it to be exactly the same as the App Store version, it communicate with the same server which communicates with the same FB app.

Answer (score 15):

I've run into this same problem and you can specify two separate bundle Ids in your Facebook app settings. Under "Settings->Basic->Native iOS App->iOS Bundle ID" you can add both the bundle Id of your normal app and the bundle Id of your ad-hoc test version.

For example:

```
com.devname1.appname
com.devname2.appname
```